# Access cell color value of datagridview when it has been set via the cellpainting event args

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My searches regarding this have only turned up how to set the color of a datagridview cell, whether that be in the formatting, cell painting, or databound events.

The code that I'm trying to work with is currently setting the cellstyle.backcolor through the datagridview event args in the cellpainting event:

```
Private Sub dgvAncientCode_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgvResults.CellPainting
  If dgvAncientCode.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Blah" Then
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
  End If
```

This works--the specified cells do show up as red--but how can I access this value elsewhere in code?  When I check the cell.style it's set to the default, yet it displays on the screen as red.

I know there is a lot wrong with this code, but I'm still relatively new and I'm supporting a lot of legacy stuff that's comprised of every worst practice you can think of.  I did come up with a workaround for this by setting the cell.style.backcolor instead of the e.CellStyle.BackColor, which lets me access the value later, but I'm also trying to understand what was happening with the original code.  I hate making things work without understanding why, mainly because I know I might be missing something important.

I apologize if this isn't clear or if it's been asked before.  I've searched for a couple hours here and elsewhere, so hopefully I didn't miss it.

Edit for additional information:  There is a button click event that iterates through the datagridview using a for each loop.  That is being used to set the cell color of a custom excel export class.  This did not work because none of the cells in the datagridview had a value on the cell.style.backcolor property, even though they show as red in the form.  If the cell displays as Red in the form, I should be able to access that somehow--at least, I think I should.

Comment: `but how can I access this value elsewhere in code?` the real question is what are you wanting to do to get this value, right now it seems nothing... Are you wanting to get the `CellStyle.BackColor` is that what you are asking? If so in what event/method are you wanting to retrieve this, what are the conditions. You see there is a lot of information missing to help you. Please update your question with further details...

Comment: Since "Red" just indicates the state of something else - the column name, why not use that instead of the color "elsewhere"?

Answer (score -1):

Try one of this. Maybe it can help you. "yourdatagrid.ControlStyle", "yourdatagrid.ItemStyle".

Comment: A `DataGridView` doesn't have a `ControlStyle` or an `ItemStyle` property.

Comment: My bad, DataGridView doesn't have but DataGrid does.